# Two DIV aside with no break on small screen and flexible width

Tags: html, break

I want 2 divs aside and they have to stay aside. If the screen is too small I don't want the two divs under each other. The first DIV has a fixed width of 400px, the second DIV can be between 150px and infinite. The height is both fixed at 300px.
How can I do that? I already tried with float, but that causes the DIVs to break if the screen is too small.
Making a wrapper-div around with a large width would work, but looks ugly and buggy.

Answer (score 0):

Create a wrapper div and give it `display: table-row; min-width: 550px;`, and then make the divs inside it have `display: table-cell;`. Something like this:

```
.container
{
    display: table-row;
    min-width: 550px;
}

.container > div
{
    display: table-cell;
    height: 300px
}

.container > div:first-child
{
    width: 400px;
}

.container > div:last-child
{
    min-width: 150px;
}
```

And then this for the HTML:

```
<div class="container>
    <div>I have 400px width.</div>
    <div>I have at least 150px width, and am next to the other guy.</div>
</div>
```

Here, have a **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SJxwA/2/)**

Comment: That doesn't work. The second div still goes to a new line when the content inside is too wide. 4ex if you insiert a 2000px width div.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like the below;

HTML

```
<div id="containerdiv">     
   <div id="fixeddiv">&nbsp;</div>
   <div id="elasticdiv">
      <div id="div2000">&nbsp;</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#containerdiv{
   min-width:550px;
}

#fixeddiv{
   height:300px;
   width:400px;
   background:red;
   float:left;
}

#elasticdiv{
   height:300px;
   overflow:hidden;
   min-width:150px;
   background:blue;
}

#div2000{
  width:2000px;
  background:yellow;
  float:left;
}
```

How Divs will appear
[image: How divs will appear]

Comment: That doesn't work. The second div still goes to a new line when the content inside is too wide. 4ex if you insiert a 2000px width div.

Comment: Are you giving a float to the div inside the second div because that might be an issue?

Maybe you can show us your code

Comment: still doesn't work. my new code:
   <div style="min-width: 550px; height: 100px;">
    <div style="float: left; width: 400px; height: 100px; background-color: #CC2467;">
     first
    </div>
    <div style="min-width: 150px; height: 100px; background-color: #00415E; overflow: hidden;">
     <img src="img/zombie.jpg" style="width: 500px; height: 100px;"/>
     <img src="img/zombie.jpg" style="width: 500px; height: 100px;"/>
     <img src="img/zombie.jpg" style="width: 500px; height: 100px;"/>
     <img src="img/zombie.jpg" style="width: 500px; height: 100px;"/>
    </div>
   </div>

Comment: I cannot view the images. Which browser are you using? So without the images the div is still not floating to the left? And which doctype are you using?